# VSS: How do I recover from "File <foo> has been destroyed, and cannot be rebuilt."?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

We're running Visual SourceSafe 6.0 (build 8163).

In one project, there's an old label I want to do a Get on, but a few files have been added *and destroyed* since that label was created.

Now everytime I try to do a Get on the label - for each destroyed file - I get the warning "File  has been destroyed and cannot be rebuilt, do you want to continue?", (which seems completely stupid, since the destroyed files never existed before the label was set).

I've tried adding files with the same name, but that didn't help. I also tried deleting (not destroying) those added files, but that didn't help either.

I *really* want to be rid of the warning, since the home-cooked building app we use to build all the projects doesn't handle this error/warning, and hence can't Get the label requested and build that project.

Help!

(and no, running VSS is not by choice, trust me, I was hoping never to see it again after the first time I was forced to use it, which was ten years ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a problem in 6.0d.  See:
 
hxxp://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=118182

You might want to look more into the vss automation documentation, I'm pretty sure there's a way for you to make it answer yes to this question by default.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx31h1wk%28VS.80%29.aspx